# will using low level api call e.g fork() in iOS app will lead to app rejection?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I am using fork() to check whether app sandbox is intact (i.e device is not jailbroken).
will using fork() result in app rejection?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about predicting what Apple will do. Ask Apple.


Comment: @Wooble, your suggestion is a bad idea for multiple reasons: (1) There's many gray areas in what Apple allows, and asking them directly may call attention to the issue in a way that makes it less likely for your app to get approved (either because they notice YOU asking about it, or notice developers in general discussing it, at which point they formulate a new policy on the API, when previously there was none). (2) It's entirely possible that you get a faster answer on SO, or that you get the fastest answer by asking both places. (3) You only get 2 tech support incidents per year.

Comment: Regarding the "prediction" aspect, that's bogus, too.  We know this isn't an Apple site.  The guy is asking for the experience, or best guess, of iOS developers, and there are plenty here.  If someone can answer by pointing to Apple documented policy, or even provide anecdotal evidence about their own apps, then that's beneficial to the question's asker.  Nobody is asking for legally binding data.  Censoring these kinds of questions is silly.  Finally, even if you **did** ask Apple, they aren't always consistent between reviewers, so there's still no guarantee of correctness.